# Scrapy:requests didn't obey the LIFO rules

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have written a spider and it does crawl some links.But the order of the link is not right and it didn't crawl some links though the request of those link has been sent.
Here is my code:

```
class DoubanSpider(Spider):
    name = "doubanspider"
    download_delay = 10
    allowed_domains = ["douban.com"]
    start_urls = [
       'http://movie.douban.com/subject/25864085'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = DoubansciencefictionItem()
        print "processing" + str(response.url)
        grade = sel.xpath('//div[@id="interest_sectl"]//strong/text()').extract()
        item['grade'] = str(grade).encode('utf-8')
        grade0 = grade[0].encode('utf-8')
        if float(grade0)<7.7:
            return
        filmurl = str(response.url)
        film    = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()

        item['film'] = [n.encode('utf-8') for n in film]
        item['url'] = filmurl.encode('utf-8')


        yield item

        urls = sel.xpath('//div[@class="recommendations-bd"]//dt//a/@href').extract() 

        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parse)
```

---

According to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html the links it crawls should follow this order(namely,DFO and I just write the last number of the link):

```
25864085-20326665-7065154-1044013…………
```

but actually the links follow:

```
25864085-20326665-7065154-7046723…………-1291843-6722879
```

well,I think maybe the links follow BFO but if they follow BFO,the order should be:

```
25864085-20326665-7065154-7046723…………-1291843-3274505
```

I can't figure out what order the spider crawls in.